# Docker can't run with Bamboo on Windows

Tags: docker, bamboo

I am running Bamboo and Docker on my windows environment. I cam execute docker with no issues from the command prompt. But Bamboo is not found the docker executable?  i have it properly configured in the Server Capability `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe"` in Bamboo I believe.

```
com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskException: Failed to execute task
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.service.BuildService.execute(BuildService.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.tasks.cli.DockerCliTask.execute(DockerCliTask.java:60)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.lambda$executeTasks$3(TaskExecutorImpl.java:317)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.executeTaskWithPrePostActions(TaskExecutorImpl.java:246)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.executeTasks(TaskExecutorImpl.java:317)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.execute(TaskExecutorImpl.java:118)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.build.pipeline.tasks.ExecuteBuildTask.call(ExecuteBuildTask.java:74)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent.build(DefaultBuildAgent.java:216)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl$1.call(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:139)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl$1.call(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:130)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.variable.CustomVariableContextImpl.withVariableSubstitutor(CustomVariableContextImpl.java:221)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl.waitAndPerformBuild(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:129)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent$1.run(DefaultBuildAgent.java:138)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.utils.BambooRunnables$1.run(BambooRunnables.java:51)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWith(ImpersonationHelper.java:31)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWithSystemAuthority(ImpersonationHelper.java:20)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper$1.run(ImpersonationHelper.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.client.DockerException: Error running Docker build command
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.client.DockerCmd.build(DockerCmd.java:189)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.service.BuildService.execute(BuildService.java:40)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: com.atlassian.utils.process.ProcessException: Error executing 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker' build --force-rm=true --tag=reaper:1.0 C:\Users\twoen\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\BOUN-BD-DOC
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.process.DockerTaskProcessService.execute(DockerTaskProcessService.java:60)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.docker.client.DockerCmd.build(DockerCmd.java:185)
```

I can run docker just fine from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker"
```

Am I missing some configuration in Bamboo on Windows?

error in bamboo:

```
09-Jan-2018 21:17:14    Starting task 'Build Docker image' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-docker-plugin:task.docker.cli'
09-Jan-2018 21:17:14    Unable to find executable at "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe". Will try to run it anyway.
```

Comment: gave up, and ran bamboo on unix based system.